# "Cannot insert breakpoint.Cannot access memory at address" error in Android ndk-gdb native code debugging

Tags: android, eclipse, remote-debugging, native-code, ndk-gdb

I have been trying to debug native C++ code in Android application using ndk-gdb for last 4 days. but i keep getting this error.[Cannot insert breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HOK2.jpg)

i have followed this tutorial using-eclipse-for-android-cc-debugging in mhandroid in wordpress website ( please note that i could not provide more than 2 links.)

After i set a breakpoint in eclipse, i have launched eclipse as debug as application. it hits a breakpoint in java code. then i ran ndk-gdb-eclipse (as per tutorial) in Cygwin. Everything runs fine in ndk-gdb. Please see the image below,
[ndk-gdb runs in cygwin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsDYE.jpg)

Then i launch debug as C/C++ application in eclipse, i am getting the error 
"cannot insert breakpoint"

i have checked all posts here but there is no solution for this error.

Can anyone please throw some light on this issue ? Thanks in Advance.